# Renaming table's column name with Greek letters in kable

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer, kable, kableextra

I am creating presentation using R Markdown with PDF (Beamer) as output. I am using library kableExtra for some formatting.

The following code gives me the expected result

```
library(knitr)
# library(kableExtra)

# create data frame
df <- data.frame(mean = c(1,2,3), beta = c(5,6,7))

# print data frame to slide
knitr::kable(df,
  col.names = c("mean", "$\\beta_t$"))
```

However, when I use library(kableExtra) as in code below, the printed PDF show $\beta_t$ instead of the Greek letter beta.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

# create data frame
df <- data.frame(mean = c(1,2,3), beta = c(5,6,7))

# print data frame to slide
knitr::kable(df,
  col.names = c("mean", "$\\beta_t$"))
```

Is there any good way to rename the column name to Greek letter while using library(kableExtra)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `escape = FALSE` in the call to `kable()`:

```
# print data frame to slide
knitr::kable(df,
  col.names = c("mean", "$\\beta_t$"),
  escape = FALSE)
```

This produces

[image: screenshot]

It looks a little nicer using `booktabs = TRUE`:

[image: screenshot]

but you'll need to add

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
```

to the document YAML [since you're using beamer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316275/2554330).

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solves the problem.