# How to add arguments from kable() in modelsummary() with output as kableExtra

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra, modelsummary

I recently discovered R package `modelsummary` from answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65677675/stargazer-for-ardl-packages-output-error-unrecognized-object-type). It appears that the output of summary table created by `modelsummary` can be of class `kable_knitr` which can be fed into other functions from `kableExtra`, such as `kable_styling`.

However, I am stuck at how to specify values for other options from the function `kable()` into the `modelsummary()` function. One obvious way could be to get a `data.frame` output and than input that into `kable`. Is there a better alternative (so that I can avoid fixing the `data.frame` output?

I am particularly looking for `kable()` options, `escape=F` (to insert greek letters in latex output - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755431/renaming-tables-column-name-with-greek-letters-in-kable)) and `booktabs=T`.

A reproducable example:

```
x=rnorm(100)
mod1=arima(x,order = c(1,0,1))
modelsummary(mod1, output = 'kableExtra', coef_rename = c('ar1'='$x_{t-1}$', 
                                                           'ma1'='$\\epsilon_{t-1}$')) %>% 
  kable_styling(latex_options = 'HOLD_position')
```

In the above table, I am trying to rename the variables to math style, which would work in `kable()` if the names were given as they have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` ellipses are pushed forward to the `kbl` function automatically. Valid arguments like `escape` can be passed directly to `modelsummary`.

Note that for the reasons explained in the "post-processing" note of the `output` argument documentation, I prefer to specify directly what output format I need before post-processing functions, otherwise `kableExtra` will prep an HTML table by default:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(modelsummary)
x=rnorm(100)
mod1=arima(x,order = c(1,0,1))

modelsummary(
  mod1, 
  output = "latex",
  coef_rename = c('ar1'='$x_{t-1}$', 'ma1'='$\\epsilon_{t-1}$'),
  escape = FALSE)
```

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\toprule
  & Model 1\\
\midrule
$x_{t-1}$ & 0.337\\
 & (0.368)\\
$\epsilon_{t-1}$ & -0.490\\
 & (0.335)\\
intercept & 0.007\\
 & (0.068)\\
\midrule
Num.Obs. & 100\\
AIC & 267.6\\
BIC & 278.0\\
Log.Lik. & -129.808\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Also note that `modelsummary` already calls `kable_styling` once internally, and that adding `kable_styling` to a latex table produced by `kableExtra` can sometimes produce weird results because `kableExtra` will nest tables within tables. (Note: I plan to submit a bugfix to `kableExtra` about this.)

```
data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 2:3) %>%
  kbl("latex") %>%
  kable_styling() %>% 
  kable_styling() %>%
  kable_styling()
```

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
\centering\begin{table}[H]
\centering\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{r|r}
\hline
a & b\\
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
2 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Thanks again Vincent. Didn't find this info about `...` in the vignette, so asked here. After reading this I feel I should have attempted at least once. But thanks. Do you think you should include this info in documentation?